# Нужна ли запятая в предложении c деепричастием?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Можно ли жить не нарушая закон?"  Или здесь всё-таки оборот ближе к устойчивому выражению?

Comment: @shampar, Тут вопрос в вопросе, но чем "внешний" вопросительный знак лучше "внутреннего"?

Comment: @shampar, Эврика! Нашел у Мильчина: ставится только "внутренний" знак. Печорин спрашивает: "И зачем было судьбе кинуть меня в мирный круг честных контрабандистов?" (8.7.3. Отсутствие знака препинания после закрывающих цитату кавычек)

Comment: Первая часть (о Печорине) — повествовательная. В вопросе же, она вопросительная. Не подходит пример. Вы же правильно заметили: тут вопрос в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, запятая вполне оправдана.

Устойчивого выражения тут нет, как нет и самого такого императивного правила, что устойчивые выражения с деепричастием не требуют обособления.

Тут сомнения могут быть по другой причине. Не требуют обязательного обособления деепричастия в выраженной функции обстоятельства. В вашем примере "не нарушая закон" действительно выступает таким характерным обстоятельством, но на практике это правило применяется почти исключительно к одиночным деепричастиям. В сочетании с "законом" наше деепричастие уже образует деепричастный оборот и требует обоcобления.

Answer (score 1):

**Можно ли жить, не нарушая закон**?   Деепричастный оборот обособляется (не является устойчивым оборотом). В предложении делается пауза.

Сравнить: **Можно ли жить без нарушения закона?** Падежная форма с тем же обстоятельственным значением не обособляется. Делается только небольшая пауза, обозначающая изменение тона.

Деепричастные обороты обычно обособляются, тем не менее встречаются **варианты без обособления:**

**Можно жить и не нарушая закон.** При наличии усилительной частицы И оборот не обособляется. (Можно прожить и не хвастая умом).

**Он мог работать не покладая рук** (= усердно, старательно). Деепричастный оборот не обособляется (является устойчивым оборотом).

**Это упражнение делают сидя на стуле.**  Деепричастный оборот не обособляется в значении наречия.